# google analytics- classcasexception

Tags: android, google-analytics

i'm new to android and try to implement google analytic in to my project where its shows classcastexception in below set of code:

```
 Tracker t = ((AnalyticsHelper) MainActivity.this.getApplication()).getTracker(
            TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
```

And this is my AnalyticsHelper class:

```
public class AnalyticsHelper extends Application {


    // The following line should be changed to include the correct property id.
    private static final String PROPERTY_ID = "UA-xxxxxxxx-x"; // My Property id.

    public static int GENERAL_TRACKER = 0;

    public enum TrackerName {
        APP_TRACKER, // Tracker used only in this app.
        GLOBAL_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all the apps from a company. eg: roll-up tracking.
        ECOMMERCE_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all ecommerce transactions from a company.
    }

    HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();

    public AnalyticsHelper()
    {
        super();
    }

    synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
        if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {

            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            analytics.getLogger().setLogLevel(LogLevel.VERBOSE);
            Tracker t = null;
            if(trackerId==TrackerName.APP_TRACKER){
                t= analytics.getTracker(PROPERTY_ID);
            }
                 mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);
                }
        return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
    }
```

i have include both jar files under libs (Google play service and google analytics services)
And also i have mention in manifest file like this:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.xxxx.xxxx.AnalyticsHelper"
            android:configChanges="screenSize"

            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" >
        </activity>
```

log_cat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxxx.xxxx/com.xxxx.xxxx.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.xxxx.xxxx.AnalyticsHelper
```

what went wrong did i missing something ..please help thanks in advance

Comment: Please post complete error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove (`AnalyticsHelper` is not activity but a custom application class)

```
<activity
    android:name="com.xxxx.xxxx.AnalyticsHelper"
    android:configChanges="screenSize"
    android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" >
</activity>
```

and add the context to application tag like this

```
<application
    android:name="com.xxxx.xxxx.AnalyticsHelper"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
```

You can get the Tracker instance by this only, no need to write that long code

```
Tracker t = ((AnalyticsHelper)getApplicationContext()).getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
```

Comment: should i want to add any meta tag for google play services??

Comment: Remove the activity tag for `AnalyticsHelper` and add `android:name="com.xxxx.xxxx.AnalyticsHelper"` in application tag. use your package name. And yes manifest should have the meta tag.

Comment: i can't able to add that application tag: its showing The <application> element must be a direct child of the <manifest> root element

Comment: Don't add complete code I have posted. Just add `android:name="com.xxxx.xxxx.AnalyticsHelper"` to your existing application tag. Don't forget to remove the activity tag of `AnalyticsHelper`.

Comment: yup..sorry it was my mistake code works dn't see any error.. but i dn't see any analytics report :(

Comment: On google analytics web console? If yes, then you should post a new question for that.

Comment: I forgot to mention one thing, report on google analytics is not available right away. Give it sometime and it should be there.